# Вопрос по полиморфным связям

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеем две модели. `User` и `Comment`

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

#comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment имеет поля `commentable_type`, `commentable_id`, `user_id`

Юзер может написать комментарий на странице другого юзера.

Получить комментарии которые написали мне, понятно:

```
current_user.comments
```

Вопрос, как получить комментарии которые написал я? Сейчас делаю так

```
Comment.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Мне кажется я делаю что-то не правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно указать наличие второй связи для пользователя.

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :my_comments, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end

#comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

User.all.first.my_comments # Комментарии, которые оставил пользователь
```

Comment: Решение супер. А если усложнить задачу? Есть еще модель `Blog`. Которая тоже имеет  `has_many :comments, as: :commentable`. Если в этом случае я делаю `User.all.first.my_comments`, то в список попадут и комменты которые я оставил в блоге. Как взять только комменты для моделей User ?

Comment: То есть нужны комменты, которые один пользователь оставил другому?

Comment: нет. нужно выбрать комменты которые я оставлял только пользователям, не в блогах. Сейчас я сделал так `user.my_comments.where(`commentable_type: 'User')

Comment: Ну, вроде, нормальный вариант. Можно ещё в скоуп этот кусок засунуть.

Comment: @AlexI это вполне сносный вариант: не надо бояться спускаться до уровня базы (всё равно придётся на сколько-нибудь сложных запросах).